# install java packages and their dependancies like pip for python

Tags: java

Is there some distribution manager for java like python has. Similiar to pip or easy_install. I wanted to install the joda-time.jar and I could do it manually. But just thought, there might be somehthing something which is easier?

My problem as written clearly one line above: I wanted to install the joda-time.jar and I did not want to do it manually. Is there some easier way to achieve this, something similar to pip( python )?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) to manage your project dependencies and build configurations.

Comment: I am already using maven and did not want to edit pom.xml file all the time. Is there a direct command line which can install the above mentioned package without editing pom.xml and which will also solve dependancies. Just like pip install packagename or apt-get install packagename

Comment: Apart from that, maven packages will be kept under the Maven Repos in a specific format. Is there no generic way, which can also be put directly under the /usr/lib/jvm/..... ?

Comment: Maven seems terribly verbose. I want to just use something akin to a one-liner `mvn install com.somebody.somepackage` or `mvn install -r requirements.maven` -- does that exist??

Answer (score 0):

You can try [depresolve](https://github.com/lambdaprime/depresolve).

For example to install snakeyaml Java library:

```
% depresolve org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.21
Resolving artifact org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.21
Downloading artifact org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.21 from central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/, default, releases+snapshots)
.....
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.21/snakeyaml-1.21.jar
```

Comment: Hi, its usual to declare your affiliation to links, unless its really obvious.